# Questions about the system $x+c_1\equiv y \pmod z$ and $d=y+c_2$ for integers $x$, $y$, $z$, $c_1$, $c_2$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, congruence-relations

> Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb Z$ and $c_1, c_2$ be two arbitrary constants (not necessarily equal).
>
> Given that $x + c_1 \equiv y \pmod z$ and $d = y+c_2$,

My queries are,

> Can I find a general solution for $x$ ? If yes, then how?

Consider another case,

> If $x$ lies between $ 0 \le x \le 256 $ and $z$ is a **Constant**. Then, looking at a set of values for $y$, What is the probability of predicting $x$ correctly?

( **The term *Predicting* stands for :** Consider among all the possible values of $x$, only 1 value of $x$ is considered as required. Say, if in a case where, $x \in {1,2,3} $. But One wants only '2' from it. Thus the probability of predicting $x$ correctly will be : $1/3$ )

**I am new here (Posting my first question) . Please help.**

**EDIT :** Let me explain with an example, Suppose, $x + c_1 \equiv y \pmod 2$. As we can see, The value of $x$ is either Even or Odd. If, it's Even, then Depending on some $c_1$ , the resultant value will be either Even or Odd. Right?
Now, obviously $y\in {0,1} $.

> Given some $y$, can I ever have probability to predict the $x$ correctly?

i.e $ (4 + 13) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, and $ (5 + 13) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$. Given, $y = {0,1}$ what will be the probability for finding $x={4,5}$ respectively ?

**Motivation :** I want to know how hard it would be to find the $x$ or there exists some formal mathematical way to obtain such a solution.

> Instead of $y$, if $d$ is given. What would be it's impact on this problem? Will it be harder to solve?

Comment: What does $d$ have to do with anything?

Comment: Here in the context until now, d has nothing to do. but, if it is seen that, just with the value of y, we can easily obtain x, then my 2nd question will be, instead of y, if only d was given. and z is known. can we get x? So, with that kept in mind, d is here stated only and further will be in need, once the primary query is cleared. :-)

Comment: The purpose of $d$ is added  and reworded for better clarification... Thanks for the Suggestion :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. If $x+c_1\equiv y \pmod z$, then, by definition of "$\operatorname{mod} z$", we we can write $$x=y-c_1+n z$$ for some arbitrary integer $n$. If $d=y+c_2$ and we're given $d$, then substitute $y=d-c_2$ and the formula becomes $$x=d+c_1-c_2+n z$$ I don't really understand your questions about "predicting" $x$. If $0\leq x\leq 250$, we know that there are $250/z$ (possibly off by one) solutions $x$: if some $x$ is a solution, then so are $x\pm z$, $x\pm 2z$, etc. (That is, every $z$-th number in the range is a solution.) Is that what you need?

Comment: Clarification is done in the Question 

Comment: Partially I got some Answers 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the congruences you have provided in general can be solved by traditional ways, as in framing:

> $x=y-c_1+nz$ and likewise.

However, if you choose to conceal the values of either $c_1$ or $c_2$, which you presumably aim at doing, that shouldn't be much of a problem each other.

> For you then have, a simple linear congruence of the form $ax+by \equiv 1 \pmod m$.

If both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are unknown,

> You could then go about replacing them by some arbitrary variable $p$ and $q$, solve for them. After having obtained the values of $p$, and $q$, what you could do is obtain the number of ways you could sum upto $p$ ( and $q$ ), using two variables.

By elementary combinatorics, this is the number :

> $(n+r-1) \choose (r-1)$ ,which equals $n+1$ in this case, because evidently $r=2$

You could then have a good-enough searching algorithm with corresponding lower and upper bounds set, that would land you with the desired values of $c_1$ and $c_2$'. Binary search would do it for you in $log(n)$ time. So, that could be something.

Thank You.